# Can I copy my Windows recovery partition to a USB and boot from it?

Tags: windows-7, boot, recovery-disk, recovery-partition

Of course it's not quite this easy, but are there steps for doing what the title says?

It's a long story but I was dual-booting Linux and had a system meltdown of sorts. As such, my Windows bootloader has been erased and I cannot boot into that OS. I do, however, have a Linux live-USB through which I have access to my drives.

Is there anyway to make use of this recovery partition and boot from it to re-install Windows?

Comment: No need to reinstall just because the boot loader is gone. Is the Windows partition itself still intact?

Comment: The windows partition is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on a Windows 7 disc, you can boot from that and run a startup repair.  Should fix you right up.

If you can't get a hold of a Win7 CD, you could always use a WinPE disc (which you can get for free by downloading the WAIK from Microsoft's web site), but this is a bit more work since you will have to make the CD, boot from it, and use BOOTREC or BCDBOOT from the command line.  It depends on how comfortable with the command line you are.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows partition is OK (assuming active partition is OK too) you have just to write MBR in Windows format.

Using LiveCD (and internet connection) open command shell:

```
sudo apt-get install lilo  (this will download and install lilo)

sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr  (this will write MBR)
```